# .iml file getting regenerated after deleting

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I am using a library in my project. It is of `.aar` format. At first I added the library version 1.0 in my project. After few months there is a new version of the library. I removed previous `.aar` library from the project and deleted the folder of the library as well from the project structure. After adding the new library. I am seeing the `.iml` file of the previous library in my project and the new library is also added to the project. I tried deleting the `.iml` of the old librARY but it regenerates again. How can I solve this ?

I even tried deleting it from File->Project Structure. But it regenerate the `.iml` file of the previous library.

I am using the latest `android studio 3.1.1`.

New is the version_17(calendar-release is the old):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is **IML File**

> IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, an IDE used to develop
>   Java applications. It stores information about a development module,
>   which may be a Java, Plugin, Android, or Maven component; saves the
>   module paths, dependencies, and other settings.

You have removed the module from the application dependency. But you haven't removed it from your project `settings.gradle`

So you still have your old module in your project but you haven't used it. remove it from `settings.gradle`. Clean and rebuild project you won't see it again.